# Check if richtextbox text area is full

Tags: c#, winforms, textarea, richtextbox

I would like to display a chunk of text in a richtexbox, but limit the length to fit the text area displayed on the GUI. The user then then hit the next button and it erases the text area and continues onwards with more text in the richtextbox. Kind of like custom scroll bars for the text area, but a way to be able to tell if there is space left on the text area, incase the text font gets larger or smaller it will be dynamic? Is there an event listener for when the text area is full?

Comment: winforms? wpf? which technology are you using?

Comment: You could use a hidden vertical scroll bar.... and I'm sure there is an event which fires when this scroll is moved (or pushed by the overflow in text)... so then you could un-hide the scroll bar (is just an idea)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer. You can use:

```
Size textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(richTextBox1.Text, richTextBox1.Font);
```

for the size of the text then check `OnContentResized` event whether the `MeasureText()` is bigger then the height of the rich textbox.

Answer (score 2):

If WinForms. Overflow detection in case someone copies a bunch of text.

```
    private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if(richTextBox1.Text.Length ==maxlength){
            //textboxfull
        }
        else if (richTextBox1.Text.Length > maxlength) {
            //textbox over flow
        }
    }
```

if WPF

Markup:

```
<RichTextBox Name="rtbEditor" TextChanged="rtbEditor_TextChanged" />
```

Code:

```
private void rtbEditor_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
    string myText = new TextRange(rtbEditor.Document.ContentStart, rtbEditor.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
    if (myText.Length == maxlength) {
        //textboxfull
    }
    else if (myText.Length > maxlength) {
        //textbox over flow
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not think he means the comparison between the legth of the text and maxlength of the control but the Grafical space of the characters phwhich would lead to use `Graphics` in the winforms case

Comment: ohhh. should i delete this answer then?

Comment: Nah,maybe it is useful to someone who get here using some search terms

Comment: Well i guess someone found it useful.